# Python3 pypyodbc SQL Server call stored procedure fails

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, stored-procedures, pypyodbc

The Python 3.8.1 code that I am working with makes several calls to stored procedures, gets results, does a simple select statement passing a string -- all successfully, using pypyodbc. My last call has me stumped as it simply fails to produce any results, or fails miserably. The stored procedure updates 1 column in 3 tables based on an OrderID, and inserts 1 row in another table. Using SSMS, the call would look like this:

```
exec GK_set_order '123456'
```

where `123456` is the `OrderID`. `OrderID` is a `varchar()`. I have logged into SSMS as the user in my Python connect statement and executed that stored procedure and it works every time.

In Python, the order number is used throughout as ADCOrderID, a string. My suspicion is that the single quotes are what is biting me. My first attempt was to create a separate string and execute that string.

```
exec_SP = "exec GK_set_order '" + ADCOrderID + "'"
cur.execute(exec_SP)
```

A `print(exec_SP)` statement shows that it is exactly what I want. But I get no errors, no exceptions, and nothing is updated in the database. I've tried 20 different variations, including double and triple quotes. Nothing was effective.

Changed to:

```
exec_SP = "exec GK_set_Order(?)"
cur.execute(exec_SP, ADCOrderID)
```

Now I get an error:

> TypeError: Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row

What am I fundamentally missing?

Comment: Thank you Marc for the thoughtful edit. I will review the suggested reading.

Comment: The problem was not in the call. The problem was in the connection.
I neglected to place `autocommit=True` at the end of the connection parameters. All of the other calls were only reading data. This stored procedure updated the status lines in several tables.